# REST server or other way to do a password reminder

Tags: forms, services, users, 8

I see in the services 3 module that there is not a password reminder functionality yet although it has been [discussed](http://drupal.org/node/1303400). What I want to know is whether there is any other way that I can call for the password reminder to be triggered from an external source (i.e. using HttpClient in Android to post direct to the form). I am building an android app and have just about everything in the login/register process complete except for a password reminder functionality. Are there any examples of using java to post directly to a drupal form available?